# Google AdMob is not working with CocoaPods

Tags: ios, objective-c, admob, cocoapods, adsense

I am using CocoaPods with

pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK', '~> 7.5.1'

Banner doesn't not show

```
2015-10-07 11:35:28.977 [3895:769698] <Google> Invalid Request: {
    "activation_overlay_url" = "http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/activation_overlay.html?hl=en";
    "base_uri" = "https:";
    "enable_auto_click_protection" = 0;
    errors = "Cannot determine request type. Is your ad unit id correct?";
    "google.afma.Notify_dt" = 1444203328976;
    "pan_include" = 0;
    "request_id" = 8;
    "request_scenario" = "online_request";
    type = unknown;
    "use_webview_loadurl" = 0;
}
```

***EDIT***

```
adBanner.adUnitID = serverGadBannerIdentifier;
adBanner.delegate = self;
[adBanner setRootViewController:contrller];
[adBanner loadRequest:[self createRequestWithBanner]];
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message says "Cannot determine request type. Is your ad unit id correct?". Are you sure you're setting the ad unit id to the correct value?

Comment: Yes, That is checked, Also some error on Simulator and Device

Comment: Probably need to do at least 2 things. 1) Debug and confirm that `serverGadBannerIdentifier` has the value you expect and 2) Confirm on the AdMob admin interface that the value is valid.

Comment: Sure, I am doing, but for now I can't see problem

Comment: Does the start of the ad unit ID look like "ca-app-pub-"?

Comment: Yes it is starting "ca-app-pub-"